# Scala Spark - Map function referencing another dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes:

**df1:**

```
+---+------+----+
| id|weight|time|
+---+------+----+
|  A|   0.1|   1|
|  A|   0.2|   2|
|  A|   0.3|   4|
|  A|   0.4|   5|
|  B|   0.5|   1|
|  B|   0.7|   3|
|  B|   0.8|   6|
|  B|   0.9|   7|
|  B|   1.0|   8|
+---+------+----+
```

**df2:**

```
+---+---+-------+-----+
| id|  t|t_start|t_end|
+---+---+-------+-----+
|  A| t1|      0|    3|
|  A| t2|      4|    6|
|  A| t3|      7|    9|
|  B| t1|      0|    2|
|  B| t2|      3|    6|
|  B| t3|      7|    9|
+---+---+-------+-----+
```

My desired output is to identify the 't' for each time stamp in df1, where the ranges of 't' are in df2.

**df_output:**

```
+---+------+----+---+
| id|weight|time| t |
+---+------+----+---+
|  A|   0.1|   1| t1|
|  A|   0.2|   2| t1|
|  A|   0.3|   4| t2|
|  A|   0.4|   5| t2|
|  B|   0.5|   1| t1|
|  B|   0.7|   3| t2|
|  B|   0.8|   6| t2|
|  B|   0.9|   7| t3|
|  B|   1.0|   8| t3|
+---+------+----+---+
```

My understanding so far is that I must create an udf that takes the column `'id` and `'time` as inputs, `map` for each row, by refering to `df2.filter(df2.id == df1.id, df1.time >= df2.t_start, df1.time <= df2.t_end), and get the corresponding`df2.t`

I'm very new to Scala and Spark, so I am wondering if this solution is even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use UDF for that but all you have to do is to reuse filter condition you already defined to join both frames:

```
df1.join(
  df2,
  df2("id") === df1("id") && df1("time").between(df2("t_start"), df2("t_end"))
)
```

Comment: Since you marked this question with [tag:scala] `===` is a correct operator.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I didn't know about `===` and thought it was a typo. I corrected it back as you had it, and it works now! - What is the difference between `==` and `===`?

Comment: `===` is a SQL equality. `==` compares column objects which is not really meaningful.

Comment: The simplicity of your answer (and the expressive power of scala) really blows my mind :)